# Is this true? $\forall P(A),P(B)>0\,.\,P(A\triangle B)= 0 \,\,\, \iff\,\,\, A=B $

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

This seems right to me, but is it true?
$$\forall P(A),P(B)>0\,.\,P(A\triangle B)= 0 \,\,\, \iff\,\,\, A=B$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not true because there are sets with probability $0$, $P(C) = 0$ doesn't imply $C = \emptyset$. Although it does imply that $P(A) = P(B)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, $P(A),P(B)>0$

Comment: If there exists a non empty set $C$ with probability $0$, then your assertion is not always true. Take for instance a set $A$ such that $A \cap C = \emptyset$ and $B = A \cup C$.

Comment: So can I say that $\forall P(A),P(B)>0\, ,\,C_1 , C_2=\varnothing \, . \, A + C_1 = B + C_2$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A\triangle B=\varnothing\iff A=B$.

If $P(W)=0$ implies $W=\varnothing$ then your implication is true. Otherwise if $X$ is the whole space, $W$ is a non-empty set of probability zero, then $A=X$ and $B=X\setminus W$ are both with positive probability, and we have that $A\triangle B=W$, so $P(A\triangle B)=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, $P(A),P(B)>0$

Comment: @yuvalz: I edited.